# Implement child UIView with fixed aspect ratio to aspect fit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, aspect-ratio

I have some issue with autolayout.

We have ViewController with root view and child view.
Child view have fixed aspect ratio.
I need to fit child view in parent while rotation.
Also chid view should be centered.
Like on a picture:
[image: aspect fit demonstration]

I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView * v = [UIView new];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    v.tag = 100;
    [self.view addSubview:v];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[v]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"v":v}]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[v]|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"v":v}]];
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *c in self.view.constraints) {
        [c setPriority:800];
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint *c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:v
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                        multiplier:0.8
                                                          constant:0.];
    [c setPriority:1000];
    [v addConstraint:c];


    c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.view
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                    multiplier:1
                                      constant:0.];
    [c setPriority:1000];
    [self.view addConstraint:c];

    c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.view
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                    multiplier:1
                                      constant:0.];
    [c setPriority:1000];
    [self.view addConstraint:c];

}
```

And it's not working, it's shrinks outside superview in landscape.

Comment: Using interface builder could be very helpful. Do you especially don't want to use it or...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made it work with the following constraints:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView * v = [UIView new];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    v.tag = 100;
    [self.view addSubview:v];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(>=0)-[v]-(>=0)-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"v":v}]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(>=0)-[v]-(>=0)-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"v":v}]];

    NSLayoutConstraint *c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self.view
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                        multiplier:1.0
                                                          constant:0];
    [c setPriority:800];
    [self.view addConstraint:c];

    c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.view
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                      constant:0];
    [c setPriority:800];
    [self.view addConstraint:c];

    c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:v
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                    multiplier:0.8
                                      constant:0.];
    [c setPriority:1000];
    [v addConstraint:c];


    c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.view
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                    multiplier:1
                                      constant:0.];
    [c setPriority:1000];
    [self.view addConstraint:c];

    c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.view
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                    multiplier:1
                                      constant:0.];
    [c setPriority:1000];
    [self.view addConstraint:c];
}
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing, it's works. But it looks really tricky. Thank your, 
Arkadiusz.

Comment: Thank you very much - the key is 1. setting a maximum size with required priority as you do in the visual format, 2. set a ratio with required priority and then 3. set a fixed size with lower priority which then will scale down to the biggest possible